# Very high frequency band pass filter

Tags: passive-filter, band-pass

I designed a band-pass filter. I set the center frequency to 90 MHz. When I do an AC analysis, I see the filter graph I want, but the transient analysis results are not what I wanted.

I'm giving a single signal pulse to the input and I want to see that at the output, but the signal is distorted due to the filter.

I want to do good filtering without distorting the input signal.

What should I change in the circuit? What should I add?

I am sharing 2 filters that I have made with you.

The results of the filter circuit below are shown in the graphs. The frequency response of this filter is as I want it, but the results are very bad in the transient analysis. It distorts the input signal pulse.

Circuit:

[image]

Frequency response graph:

[image]

Filter input pulse:

[image]

Filter output pulse:

[image]

Now let's move on to the other filter circuit with a good transient result graph.

This filter circuit and its results are shown below.

Circuit:

[image]

Frequency response graph (this graph is not suitable.)

[image]

Filter input pulse:

[image]

The pulse I get at the comparator output (the results I want should be roughly like this.)

[image]

Comment: I'm signal is linear at best with a 30 dB range and the Bode plot has a ridiculous >400 dB range so if you compare the plots just looking at the top 30 dB and that higher Q is what makes the difference, not the DC

Comment: *But Dc analysis results do not occur as I want. I'm giving a single signal pulse to the input* That's not DC analysis. In a DC analysis, the signal does not change over time, so simulationg a pulse response is impossible in a DC analysis. What you're doint is a time-analysis called **transient analysis**.

Comment: What bandwidth do you want, and why?

Comment: You can't eat your cake and have your cake. If you want a specific transient response then design your filter to suit that.

Comment: Are really needed R7, R14, R12, R16 ? In such filters ... are only needed the first and the last 50 Ohm. https://rf-tools.com/lc-filter/

Answer (score 2):

The passive filter response looks normal for a highish-Q bandpass.

The active filter response is different because it doesn't work: the opamps don't have a negative power supply, yet the circuit would require them to output a negative voltage, so they're stuck in clipping when output voltage is near zero. In addition, the maximum input voltage spec of 4.5V is violated.

So you should use +/-2.5V power supplies for the opamps, and use a lower input amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is far from being accurate.  A BPF will slow down risetime ( due to -3dB BW) and cause ringing whenever Q>1. Its inverse is called Damping Factor. It seems you need a digital solution is a time delay, being a one-shot shorter than the input pulse.

To realize your transfer function, let's look at what you want.

### +ve Pulse narrower

\$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$Input:  \$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$Output

\$t_{PW50}\$, width \$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$~some pulse like 40 ns\$~~~~~~~~\$< 10 ns
\$t_R\$ , rise time  \$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$ ~1 V/ns\$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$same
V range\$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$5 V\$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$ same
\$t_{p}\$ Propagation delay: \$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$  TBD
Load Capacitance **[pF]**: \$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\$ TBD assume 30 pF max

- A typical trace over ground plane 3cm/ pF +IC load   (let's assume 30 pF, a standard datasheet load).
- A ground plane is needed to lower the impedance if prop. delay approaches or exceeds rise time.

Classic One shots are found in logic '123 package.

74HC123: Transition time 15 ns max @ 4.5V  , PWmin = 45 ns typ @ 5V  ([TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc123.pdf))  This does not meet your requirements.

[74ALC123](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/74AHCT123APW-118/1229602): is lower output capacitance (4 pF) and half the driver resistance. ~ *25 ohms typ @ 5V* but 45 ohms max @ 4.5V = Vol/Iol

Pulse Width (min) = 5ns  . This looks similar to your requirements which you need to get into a habit of articulating in a list such as above.

For faster risetimes, use Current Mode Logic (CML), which has fewer choices and excludes one-shots. But you can make one with NAND gates and an ***[RC delay as I have done here.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCBMB0CsCmBaMAGELoA4DskCcYAzJoQGyG4pGEixqy31JhgBQYsEepUALGpBSY%20aAbVrtOUIeDyQQhQbPliGsVgHcFSsNh6K0YOek3ThkfmaspJEA8pC9FDsfVP2j8%204OE2tT%20U9HUl4XU25wPRAIyAsTLQjdHh9Inj9onjBeUMSomwAlR2Es0ORM7PAoKDoUWtqoOAaGUThWACci6p5eYoq0Xmx0xIqe8D7w5Nhu8ymTAGNOyFnRwhRQw2Y7aCJsbBYUQjx%20fFx0aFq2AHNO1dCVpVFWAHtwQ3RHFDw8cQwqJffAmhCM9xBB%20p9vs1znU8Hopv9VAoQZl3vwvj9obVYaR4c0qvpWEA)***

Then you may achieve sub-nanosecond pulse widths with a suitable controller impedance board design with test points, tip/ring probes and/or SMC connectors, cable with 50 ohm load.

Answer (score 0):

Made with **microcap 12**,  [spectrum-soft.com](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm)

Here an example (passive Butterworth standard) of a **90 MHz** (**center** frequency filter), **10 MHz** **bandpass**. Ok, there are some ... for any needs.

What one should get ... AC Analysis and TRAN Analysis (impulse).

One should note the "symmetry" of curves (**AC** and **TRAN** impulse).

[image]

[image]

[image]